# CSS changes doesn't work in Firefox 17.0.1 using Wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, firefox, css, wordpress-theming

I'm using the [Simple Retail Plugin](http://whatwouldjessedo.com/simple-retail-menus/) and added this CSS class to it's css(display.css):

```
.round
{
border-width: 28px;
-moz-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Mozilla version*/
-webkit-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Webkit version*/
-o-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Opera version*/
-ms-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*IE syntax when it does support this prop*/
border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Standard version*/
}
```

Just a simple border that uses an image. I've tried to add it to the Wordpress's own stylesheet but the same problem persists.

It does work in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox.  I know that border-image CSS works in Firefox because I've tested it outside of Wordpress (v3.4.2).

I've used firebug and it shows that it does in fact use that class but for some reason doesn't show it in firefox. I even tried to change the themes.

I've googled, searched and tested for the last two days but found nothing.

Thanks for your help

Edit: I'm using MAMP.

Comment: Have you tried disabling/clearing your cache, hard-refreshing(Ctrl+F5)? Sometimes browsers, sometimes browsers and servers become pretty nasty in caching resources - which is a problem when you're developing something. Do you have any caching plugins as well?

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov Yes. Emptied cache and reloaded. Several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. It seems after Firefox updated to 15.01 they made some changes how it reads the css. You need to add:

```
border-style;solid;
```

after border-image css tag. It should look like this:

```
.round
{
border-width: 28px;
-moz-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Mozilla version*/
-webkit-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Webkit version*/
-o-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Opera version*/
-ms-border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*IE syntax when it does support this prop*/
border-image: url("../images/frame2.png") 28 28 round; /*Standard version*/

border-style;solid

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue with one of my sites just last night.

The only thing I found that worked was to update the stylesheet and save it in wordpress editor, go into your database, edit the site url in the wp-options table, rename the folder the site is in to what you changed it to in the database and it will have updated.

Comment: No luck. :/ Had to change SiteUrl *and* Home in the database to make the homepage open.

Comment: Whats the URL to your site?

Comment: I'm using it locally with MAMP.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry you said.  My bad.  I know this sounds silly but have you restarted the server fully & cleared its cache if it has one? I also suggest downloading Microsoft Web Matrix 2, installing the Wordpress add-on and installing the theme.  Web Matrix will also install IIS and I found that it themes where correct on Web Matrix but nowhere else.

Comment: I turned off XCache for PHP but the problem is still there. Funny thing is that it doesn't show in Firefox. It shows inside chrome and safari. I have a feeling that the css gets overridden but then I use firebug and see that it uses that class, but just not rendering it.

Comment: I installed firefox 13 and opened the page and it works. I'll install version 17 and see what happens. If it breaks then I'll bug report it to the mozilla team.

Comment: Its also possible you have an add-on in 17 that your site does not agree with.  Try starting FF17 without add-ons.

Comment: I just checked with version 16 and it's broken there also. So I'll probably ignore it because it's at least two versions old and probably a feature than a bug. I'll start a clean version of newest firefox and I'll see if it help. But I doubt it. I think they did something to the css renderer. Edit: No changes with the add ons off.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to try a clean install of FF17 and see if it works.  Or i use an app in Chrome called "Chrome UA Spoofer".  It lets you view web pages is a bunch of browsers and a bunch of browser versions, that would be worth a look into.  Its very accurate also.